# Adding inline CSS to JS class with React Fragment

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I was following this article https://prawira.medium.com/react-conditional-import-conditional-css-import-110cc58e0da6 to conditionally lazy-load CSS stylings in my React app. The method described involves creating a dummy JS class, eg.

```
import React from 'react';
import './my-styles.css';

const Theme = () => (<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>);

export default Theme;
```

So that it can be used like this:

```
const styles = React.lazy(() => import("./theme"))
...
return (
<>
   <Suspense fallback={<></>}>
      {styles}
   </Suspense>
   <MyApp />
</>
);
```

I will need to be able to lazy load many CSS stylesheets, and I don't want to create the same JS wrapper over and over again for each one. Is there a way to combine the wrapper with inline CSS, or perhaps make one wrapper for all of the styles (such that the lazy-loading process still only loads the specific one I want?)

Comment: Sorry, it's not exactly clear what you are asking for?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I am asking for a way to combine the .css and ,js files in this example by somehow applying inline CSS to the ```const Theme = () => (<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>);```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a theme that will decide what styles have to be loaded as in the article you are refferring to:

```
const ThemeSelector = ({ children }) => {
  const CHOSEN_THEME = localStorage.getItem('TYPE_OF_THEME') || TYPE_OF_THEME.DEFAULT;
  return (
    <>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<></>}>
        {(CHOSEN_THEME === TYPE_OF_THEME.LIGHT_MODE) && <LightTheme />}
        {(CHOSEN_THEME === TYPE_OF_THEME.DARK_MODE) && <DarkTheme />}
      </React.Suspense>
      {children}
    </>
  )
}
```

In the expample you show there is no condition, by the way. It always loads `'./my-styles.css'`

Comment: That's not what I am asking - I know that the code I shared will always load ```'./my-styles.css```. I am asking for a better way to define a 'Theme' than the method suggested in the article - the code excerpt you posted is where the Theme is actually used, which I am not asking about.